# Looking for an algorithm/class for counting IP addresses (histogram)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, ip-address, histogram

I need a simple class to count the distribution (histogram) of IP addresses from a network monitoring system. There might be anywhere from 1 to 10<sup>10</sup> packets, with anywhere from 1 to 2<sup>32</sup> addresses (or more, if we have an IPv6 interface). What I'm ideally looking for is a C++ class that will automatically create the histogram and then, when a limit is reached, start combining the less popular nodes through some kind of prefix routing.

Does anybody know of something like this, or do I need to write it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need exact numbers for the most popular IP addresses?  Or would you be okay with approximate answers for any IP address queried?

Comment: @templatetypedef, I'm okay with approximate numbers.

Comment: what is this limit you are talking about? A difference between the most popular and the less popular one?

Comment: and what if an unpopular one becomes popular after it's been combined?

Comment: I believe that, when making an histogram, one either keeps the say 4 most prominent values, or keeps the values that are above a certain threshold (say 10%). Is that threshold the limit you are talking about?

Comment: @didierc, the problem with what you suggest is that you don't know which are the most prominent values until you've passed through all of the data.

Comment: I don't see how you can avoid going through all the data to make statistics, unless you try something like @templatetypedef 's answer. What you would like is something like a priority queue, where it is possible to group subsets in single entries of the queue, until the elements of these subsets grow out of it when becoming more popular. Somehow, I wonder if this is not what IP stacks do when classifying streams and prioritizing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed an algorithm for solving this problem. The algorithm stores the IP address counts in a radix tree / prefix tree. Each node records the next bit of the address, and a count if it is a terminal node. Where there are too many nodes the nodes are combined starting at extent of the tree; nodes with leaves that have the lowest counts are combined first.

It's very elegant and very fast. I can post the C++ code if there is interest.

Comment: It's available in tcpflow at the moment. I'll be writing an article about it shortly.

Answer (score 6):

What you're describing sounds like a perfect use case for the **[Count-Min sketch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count-Min_sketch)** data structure.  This data structure is used to approximate the frequency of various elements from a data stream and can be tuned to precisely use up a certain amount of memory.  Moreover, given a fixed memory limit, you can adjust how accurate it is and how close to the exact answer you'd like it to be.  My understanding is that Google uses this data structure to identify frequent searches without having to use a ridiculous amount of disk space.

As an added plus, the data structure never underestimates the true frequency of a given value.  That is, if you want to query how frequently you've seen a given IP address, the Count-Min sketch will always give you a value that is no smaller than the true number.

The Count-Min sketch is extremely easy to implement - you just need a bunch of different hash functions and a 2D array.  You can also find a variety of different implementations of the Count-Min sketch **[at Google's page on the data structure.](https://sites.google.com/site/countminsketch/code)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow. That's great. I remember that one of my friends at MIT told me about this a few years ago and I promptly forgot about it. Glad you know about it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I downloaded the code. Strangely, it doesn't actually do what I need, which is it doesn't combine the leaves. It's close, but not quite there.

Comment: @vy32- My apologies - I interpreted your reply to my comment to mean that you just needed good estimates of IP address frequency.  I didn't realize you still needed coalescing.  However, I think you could use the CM sketch as a building block here by using it to find heavy hitters, then filtering out everything else.

Comment: no need to apologize at all!  The sketch stuff is pretty neat. Very clever application of Bloom filters. It's just not the right thing. I need something that's aware of prefix routing (see my comment on BlueRaja's note. I suspect I'll just have to hack something up....

Comment: @vy32: Count-Min Sketch supports range queries, would that not be enough?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, the problem with the sketch is that it doesn't collapse the elements in the ranges as necessary. However I now have a very nice implementation based on prefix trees. Let me know if you would like to see it.

Comment: @vy32: Sorry, I assumed that "requirement" was just because you'd like to save space, and like to be able to group some IPs together.  The fact that Count-Min Sketch is constant-space, along with the fact that it supports range-queries, satisfies both of those in a different way, making your requirement unnecessary.  Unless there was another reason?

Comment: I don't know in advance if the software is going to be run with a few hundred packets or a few hundred billion packets. I'd like correct answers as much as possible. Both the prefix tree and the sketch degrade in resolution when they have too much stored in them, but the prefix tree degrades in a way without creating false positives and in a way that makes sense with respect to the underlying data type.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @templatetypedef, for the approximate solution.

For completeness, if one needs to store exact counts, there's no way around storing the exact numbers.  However, depending on your requirements, you might be able to reduce the space needed significantly *(for instance, 10.*.*.* and 192.68.*.* ips can never be publically routed; and many others, such as 25.*.*.*, currently are not being publically routed)*.  You may also *(again depending on your requirements)* be able to count large groups of less-important ips together.

If you could lower down the space requirements far enough, you could store the counts in memory as compactly as possible using a `bitset`.  If there is no simple way to map ip-address to bitset-address, you'll need to use something like a [succinct trie](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=120) to map them.  A succinct trie would require one byte (amoritized) per ip-group.

And, if you can't lower it far enough, you'll likely need to use a database, and accept the performance hit.

Comment: A database can't work here. One thing I'm thinking of doing is having a map of [address/mask] values and then when the map has more than N values searching for the entry with the minimum value, decreasing the value of the mask, and then combining all of the nodes.  So if I have a single 192.168.1.254/32 value and  I have 9,999 other values and need to free up a slot, I'll change the slot to 192.168.1.254/31, look for everything it can combine with, rebalance, and continue....

Comment: @vy32: Typically in a database you wouldn't do that; you'd store the data in as granular a fashion as possible, then aggregate it later when actually querying the data *(and when that becomes too slow, you set up a separate database specifically for aggregating data, usually called the [database warehouse](http://goo.gl/WgL7N))*.  However, if you're only storing 10k or so IPs and aggregating from there, you could likely store them in memory using a binary (or 256-ary) [trie](http://goo.gl/0R6n5).  Just point each IP (or group of ip's) to the memory-location containing the count.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on Border Gateway Protocol (BGP) or GRiDA algorithms.

Comment: Those are both routing algorithms. I'm not routing, I'm counting. I'm not trying to create a connected map. I'm counting packets.